# Потеря скорости при трении Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Разрабатываю 2D игру(вид сверху) и столкнулся с проблемой реагирования на коллайдеры. Дело в том, что на сцене есть спрайт персонажа с Rigidbody2D, BoxCollider, скрипт управления персонажем:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(x * speed, y * speed);
    }
```

Если подойти к стене(TilemapCollider), и зажать две кнопки, одну в сторону стены, а вторую в сторону движения, например стена находится ниже игрока, тогда зажму S(вниз) и A(влево). Тогда игрок потеряет скорость до (7.2,0), если учитывать, что speed = 12. А в какой-то прекрасный момент вообще перестанет двигаться, пока не сделаешь движение назад или вверх.
Настройки RB2D игрока:
[image: Rigidbody2D игрока]
Здесь персонаж зависает и не двигается влево. Как будто маленький камушек мешает прокатиться.
[image: Зависание персонажа]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело здесь в физическом материале - вы можете увидеть поле под него на вашем скрине.
Создайте новый `Physics Material 2D` в папке проекта с помощью ПКМ, поменяйте значение `Friction`(трение) в нём на нужное вам (видимо - 0) и назначьте вашему персонажу, либо в "материал по умолчанию", находящийся в настройках 2d физики проекта.

Comment: Да, сделал, теперь скорость постоянная, спасибо. Но персонаж до сих пор останавливается на соединение двух тайлов.

Comment: @XMarin, не совсем понятно, какого поведения от персонажа вы ожидаете. Он же уперся в стену, куда он пойдет? Можете скрин приложить к вопросу и уточнить его

Comment: @m-green, дополнил вопрос

Comment: @MGreen, использовал Composite Collider, зависание пропало. Спасибо за помощь!